# How do I check for error in Python to stop it from looping?

Tags: python, error-checking

I am a beginner Python learner. This keeps looping and I couldn't seem to find the error in this to get it corrected. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
sentence = "that car was really fast"
i = 1
while i > 0:
    for char in sentence:
        if char == "t":
            print("found a 't' in sentence")
        else:
            print("maybe the next character?")
```

Comment: At what point do you want it to stop looping?  The `for` loop will stop when it hits the end of `sentence`, but the `while` loop will continue forever (and restart the `for` loop that's inside of it) because `i` will never not be `1`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you just want to count the number of 't's in a given sentence? If so, you don't need the while loop. I'll post an answer on this as soon as you clarify

Comment: Thanks for responding. My goal is to run it "properly", according to my assignment. So I am presuming that I should stop once the answer is found.

Comment: @Samwise, do you mind explaining briefly the context of what "i will never not be 1" means?

Comment: You set `i = 1`, and then never set it to anything else.  `i` will therefore always be `1`, which means that `i > 0` will always be true.  It won't change by itself; there is no magic that will make a program do something that you didn't tell it to do.  :)  It would be simpler to have your `while` loop be `while True:` if you want it to loop forever.  If you don't want it to loop forever, and you just want to iterate over `sentence` once in your `for` loop, you should remove the `while` loop entirely.

Comment: @Samwise I see, I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to determine whether the letter "t" is in the sentence, this can be done very simply with Python's `in` operator:

```
if 't' in sentence:
    print("found a 't' in sentence")
```

If you want to iterate over every letter in the sentence and print a line of output for each one depending on what it is, you only need a single `for` loop:

```
for char in sentence:
    if char == "t":
        print("found a 't' in sentence")
    else:
        print("maybe the next character?")
```

If you want to stop this loop as soon as you find a "t", the way to do that is `break`:

```
for char in sentence:
    if char == "t":
        print("found a 't' in sentence")
        break
    print("maybe the next character?")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Samwise, I think the second suggestion makes the best sense for what the question is asking for

Answer (score 1):

You have set `i = 1` but in the `while` loop there is nothing that changes the value of i to eventually become 0 and break out of the loop. Also, you don't even need the `while` loop because you are just iterating over the characters in the string `sentence`, so just do this:

```
sentence = "that car was really fast"

for char in sentence:
    if char == "t":
        print("found a 't' in sentence")
    else:
        print("maybe the next character?")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Daniel, your suggestion makes sense for what the question is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is to print 'found t in sentence' if the char is a 't' and else print 'maybe the next character?'.
You should not use the `while` loop in this program only `for` loop will suffice what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you @SaGaR, yes, I will remove the while loop entirely.